# Is there a way of stopping images in the post from sliding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I'm trying to get this slide the post, but if I take any tag scripts, related the slide images, all photos disappear ... I reduced the blog as much as I could and all javascripts present when removed they modify the such slide ...

But the problem is not only this .. If you click to read the full post summer that I colored a part of the post, and it is all structured differently (and in the way I want it to be) but the automatic summary modifies the post and puts the automatic slide. If I delete this part of the code for example:

```
expr:id=’"summary" + data:post.id’ style=’display:none;’
```

The post is the way I want him to stay and gives original form, but in doing so I would be missing the 'Read More' .. And I tried already add it separately but never works, because it is already in javascript and if I remove it all contains within posts will disappear ...

There are some parts of javascript that to remove it slide up to, but the photos are all big and the text is formatted the way you have javascript and does not form I edited ... Like this one:

```
// Homepage Slider and Gallery Slider
$('.post-gallery').slick({
lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: true,
adaptiveHeight:true,
autoplaySpeed: 5000,
prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-prev"><i class="fa    fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>'
});
```

I have tried to remove the plugin:

```
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

and the part of the code bellow

```
// Homepage Slider and Gallery Slider
```

and then deletes everything related to post-gallery in css, it makes the slide stop even then the post does not stay as I want but with a format that the summary made in javascript commands stay ... I do not know what to do, I've tried everything ...

> How do I know that I may not have explained right ... I'll summarize a
>   little ... I do not want to have the slide and not the text is
>   formatted so that the javascript command, I want the text to be equal
>   when clicked the title, but I want that to happen before the title is
>   clicked.

Give me any advice, some help, I really have tried everything I know, but do not know what to do anymore ...

My blog: http://1478562145.blogspot.com.br/